# C Max Sum Circular Subarray

Tags: c

So I am doing some basic exercises to get myself accustomed to C and I ran across this issue that I don't understand. For this problem, you're supposed to get the max sum of a subarray. For example:

Input:  {2, 1, -5, 4, -3, 1, -3, 4, -1}

Output: Subarray with the largest sum is {4, -1, 2, 1} with sum 6.

Input:  {-3, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4}

Output: Subarray with the largest sum is {4, -1, 2, 1} with sum 6.

So here's how I did my code:\

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //size of array A
    int size = argc - 1;
    //initializing for loop vars
    int n, i, j, k;
    //initializing index holders
    int high, low = 0;
    //counter used to copy the array
    int count = 1;
    //A array is double the size of the # of args
    int A[2*size];
    
    //Loop that fills the A array
    for(n= 0; n <2*size; n++)
    {
        //When to reset the counter so the first element is added to the A[size] to A[2*size] locations
        if (n == size)
        {
            count = 1;
        }
        ///Adds elements to the array
        A[n] = atoi(argv[count]);
        count++;
    }
    //initializing vars
    int sum, hold = 0;

    //Nested for loop that finds the Max Subarray
    for (i = 0; i <2*size-1 /*2*size - 1*/; i++)
    {
        //Reset hold var
        hold = A[i];
        for(j = i+1; j < 2*size; j++)
        {
            hold += A[j];
            //Tests current subarray sum to max subarray sum
            if(hold > sum)
            {
                //setting new max sum and indexes
                sum = hold;
                low = i;
                high = j;
            }
        }
    }
    //Print max subarray and max sum
    printf("{ ");
    for(k = low; k <= high; k++){
        if(k < high) printf("%d, ", A[k]);
        else printf("%d ", A[k]);
    }
    printf(" } \nMax Sum = %d\n", sum);
}
```

My issue is that it will occasionally break and post a ridiculous sum value but most of the time it will work fine. This is an example of my output done a few times with the above input example being used:
[PuTTY Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7HXZ.png)

Comment: Please do not post text output as an image. Copy it directly as text into the question. As for your specific problem, turn up compiler warnings. It'll tell you that `sum` is uninitialised. Reading an unintialised variable, e.g. `if(hold > sum)`,   results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: !! I did not realize that `int sum, hold = 0` did not initialize both variables to equalling 0 and that fixed it which makes a lot more sense now thank you! Also sorry about the image it was my first time posting so ill keep that in mind.

Comment: Complexity seems O(n^2). Moreover, i don't understant how you avoid counting some elements twice.

Comment: Complexity is O(n^2) and I know it can be improved I was just trying to do it as simply as possible as it was just for fun for me. Also, it is supposed to count the elements exactly twice as that was my way of making it a "circle" without having to involve circular linked lists or some other form of the data structure as it was array practice for me.